# TimePicker ONLY Bind Time

Tags: c#, wpf

I have installed WPF Toolkit Extender and want to use the TimePicker... and ONLY the TimePicker.  I have the Value bound to a String Property in my VM. The value of the TimePicker always includes the date. How do I only get the Time? Where am I going wrong? (Yes, I'm sure I'm using TimePicker and not DateTimePicker).

**XAML**

```
        <xctk:TimePicker 
                     Margin="106,178,170,256"
                     Format="Custom"
                     FormatString="hh:mm tt"
                     TimeInterval="00:15"
                     Value="{Binding Time, Mode=TwoWay}"
                     />
```

**ViewModel**

```
    private String _time;

    public String Time
    {
        get { return _time; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _time, value, () => Time); }
    }
```

**Value When Debugging**

"1/19/2018 12:00:31 AM"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Value` property of the Xceed TimePicker is a `Nullable<DateTime>`, which will contain the entire date and time values.

What I would recommend doing is binding to a property which is a `Nullable<DateTime>` (`DateTime?`), since that is what you are actually working with. If you want a string representation of, you can have a calculated property based on the `Time` property.

```
public string TimeText => String.Format("", Time);
```

You'll also have to raise the property changed event on the additional property (if necessary). It's hard to really say because I'm not sure where you need the string representation of a time as opposed to working with the actual DateTime object. One last note is you can extract the time portion of the DateTime by using the `TimeOfDay` property which returns a `TimeSpan` object.

Comment: Thank you, m-y. Do you know of any better solutions for a 'Time-Only' Picker in WPF?

Comment: I'm not aware of any `TimePicker` controls which operate on a `TimeSpan` as opposed to storing a `DateTime` value.